# Open source c++ debugger for windows

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

Does anybody know an open source C++ debugger for Windows?

It doesn't have to be good, it just has to work.  (I'd prefer one written in C++)

thanks :)

Comment: I thought gdb was available for windows as well

Comment: Why do you need the source code of a debugger? If if intereseted, you can look: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/writing_debugger_1.aspx

Otherwise, VS beats all debuggers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/)** but ofcourse!

And be assured it works as well as any debugger does :)

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any statements to the contrary, I'll assume here that [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) will work fine for you. For a comprehensive tool-chain, look to mingw.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling)](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) -- this is OPEN SOURCE -- BUT i still doubt it can beat VS 2010 debugger?

Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically these both are IDEs, but maybe that's what you mean by `debugger`.  I think you can use whatever compiler/debugger you like with them:

- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)- I'm not sure if it will remain open, seeing as Oracle bought Sun Microsystems.  It's great as a Java IDE and has C++ modules.
- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)- I use it on Linux and love it.  I can't tell you much about it on Windows though, as I've never used it on that platform. I just know it has an installer.